# Image path formatting

Tags: java, image, path

I'm trying to put an image to pdf file in my spring application. The code is

```
URL imageUrl = getClass().getResource(LOGO_PATH);
        Image logo = Image.getInstance(imageUrl);
```

I have the image in source packages in com.application.pdf -package. How do I reference to LOGO_PATH then?

```
private static final String LOGO_PATH = "/src/java/com/application/pdf/logo.gif";
```

gives me null pointerexception.

Comment: Did you try to remove "/src/java/" from your LOGO_PATH?

Comment: I guess you are using the iText library?

Answer (score 0):

You are tried to find resource in src folder, but in runtime you have to get resource from other folder, **compile folder** ( for example resource ) or from jar file, try to change your path to compile folder and I think all will be ok.
**UPDATE**
Could you provide structure of your application and I will help you to write correct path?